# download and install visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Ok, this may be the dumbest question ever, but I swear I searched for the answer and don't know what to do.

I need to install Visual Studio 2008. The free version. I need it in order to compile something.

Microsoft has a download page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7873 with a big red "download" button. This button then proceeds to download a powerpoint file. No info under "install instructions"

I have found other links that show you how to install it, but assuming that you've already got whatever it is that needs to be downloaded.

I've also found a couple of random sites where I can download it, but don't know for sure if I can trust these sites.

EDIT: I am also not having any luck finding visual studio express 2008. MS has links for 2012.

Comment: If you only need to compile something is the .Net Framework not all you need?

Comment: Open the details - `File name: Visual Studio 2008 overview.pptx`. Why would they just let people download the full version of Visual Studio 2008? Search for Visual Studio Express to find the free versions.

Comment: I couldn't read the powerpoint file. I get a message asking me to  first purchase ms office. I thought VS 2008 was free because that's what it says here: http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?q=visual+studio+2008

Comment: Re: search page, Yes, but if you look under the circle with arrow download icon, you'll see it says "document" rather than "tool" or "application"

Comment: I believe that Microsoft only offer the latest version of Visual Studio Express for download, and as you say, obtaining it from other sites may be a tad suspect.

Comment: This question is off topic, and yes, Microsoft only offers the latest version of the Express editions for download.

Comment: One particular site isn't so suspect, I mean the long lasting legal Sweden one, the pirate bay. You can see the comments and some may even be added by moderators or other trusted sources. If it's under 1Gb than is should be the Express, the larger one is the Professional (MFC & ATL included, ... and other things).

Comment: actually awsom question.

Comment: If you have a license, e.g., from your school, you can find the software at  my.visualstudio.com (including older versions like 2005)

Answer (score 139):

Visual Studio 2008: (3,30 GB)
http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81d3f35e-fa03-485b-953b-ff952e402520/VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso

MSDN Library 2008: (2,15 GB)
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=90&p=&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2f1%2ff%2f0%2f1f07c259-7ff2-4902-9205-ad1dfb87ccab%2fVS2008SP1MSDNENUX1506188.iso

To upgrade from trial version to Pro version, check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246600%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I just needed to add 64-bit support to an existing VS2008 installation, and the first link provided in this answer worked for that purpose.  I also had to download the VS2008 SP1 installer, and follow the instructions [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2009/02/02/feature-changes-in-visual-studio-2008-sp1-may-prompt-for-sqlsysclrtypes-msi/) to complete the feature update.

Comment: I needed to run an old VB6 app and as of 5/20/2020 this download still works perfectly on Windows 10. Thanks so much!

Comment: @WillRoss1: In order to run a VB6 app, you only need the redistributable VB6 runtime, not the whole Visual Studio.

Comment: @Dr.KoutheirAttouchi I know it's been a while, but I hope you can help me pointing out which file says the steps to convert to Pro from the Trial. The link you provided takes me to a download site that has several PDF files referring to Visual Studio 2005. I assume the steps are the same steps must be followed for 2008 but I would want to know which of all the pdfs must I read.

Comment: @Bisonfan95, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453262/upgrading-visual-studio-2008-from-trial-to-full-on-windows-7-beta-build-7000

Comment: Seems like the link to Visual Studio 2008 (3,3GB) isn't working any more? Ahh... you have to right-click, "save as" and then ignore the warnings from chrome...

Comment: @etalon11 try in Edge browser and its downloading for me

Answer (score 75):

For Microsoft Visual C++ 2008, not the general Visual Studio ([go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279‎](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279))

Google `Visual Studio 2008 Express` instead of just `Visual Studio 2008`. Click to the first link that appears which is a download link from Microsoft mentioned above.

Comment: Link to the C++ version died

Answer (score 40):

Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions with SP1 (english):
http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/8/E/E8EEB394-7F42-4963-A2D8-29559B738298/VS2008ExpressWithSP1ENUX1504728.iso
Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions (english):
http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/5/8B5804AD-4990-40D0-A6AA-CE894CBBB3DC/VS2008ExpressENUX1397868.iso

Comment: This one is the real one.

Comment: "afxwin.h" not found!!!

Comment: @user180574 see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543723/5222357)

Comment: @ChanTzish, thank you. A brief looking at the link convinces me that EE is not an easy way to pursue MFC development. I give it up.

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (iso)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13276

http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/3/7/a371b6d1-fc5e-44f7-914c-cb452b4043a9/VS2008SP1ENUX1512962.iso

Version: SP1
File Name: VS2008SP1ENUX1512962.iso
Date Published: 8/11/2008
File Size: 831.3 MB

Supported Operating System

```
    Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows XP
    Minimum: 1.6 GHz CPU, 384 MB RAM, 1024x768 display, 5400 RPM hard disk
    Recommended: 2.2 GHz or higher CPU, 1024 MB or more RAM, 1280x1024 display, 7200 RPM or higher hard disk
    On Windows Vista: 2.4 GHz CPU, 768 MB RAM
    Maintain Internet connectivity during the installation of the service pack until seeing the “Installation Completed Successfully” message before disconnecting.
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has 15 upvotes, that demonstrates people does votes with no reason. A service pack is an UPDATE that requires a previous version of the software to being updated, so that ISO image will require Visual Studio 2008 previouslly installed, then this is not the way to download Visual Studio 2008, this is just an update to VS2008.

Comment: @ElektroStudios The other links provided here just give you VS 2008 without the update. So this link is very useful if you need VS 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one: http://www.asp.net/downloads/essential  This has web developer and VS2008 express

Answer (score -1):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14258

which leads to:

Microsoft® Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR R2

Hope this is helpfull

Comment: It's gone as of this date.