# Visual Studio 2015 - programming for Windows CE 6.0 (Compact Framework 3.5)

Tags: c#, windows-ce

Could anybody tell me is there any way to create C# application in Visual Studio 2015 to mobile device with Windows CE 6.0 (with .NET framework 3.5 compact)?

I found SDK for VS 2008 only.

Regards,
Tomasz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Developing .NET Compact Framework apps in Post-2008 Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241978/developing-net-compact-framework-apps-in-post-2008-visual-studio)

Comment: J. Steen- no, is not a duplicate. Solution for VS 2008 not working on VS 2015.

Comment: **Post**-2008. The question has answers on the limitations of the various compact editions and as such answers what you want to know. It might not be the answer you want to hear, but it's the unfortunate way it seems to be.

Comment: Ok, It seems that there is no possibility of programming in VS higher as 2008 :/. I was looking is possible buy the VS 2008 PRO, and I do not see such a possibility :/

Comment: With an [MSDN subscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa336858.aspx) you can get access to older versions of Visual Studio, including VS2008

Answer (score 4):

To develop for WCE6 and .NET CF 3.5 the official tool is VS2008.
Install VS2008 and you will have also .NET CF 3.5 installed.
No SDK is needed: just create a smart device project and select your target CF version.
About your target WCE6 OS it need to have support for .NET CF 3.5.

See also [Can we Create Smart Device Project in VIsual Studio 2015 Professional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545992/can-we-create-smart-device-project-in-visual-studio-2015-professional)

Hope this helps