# Windows Form application on WinCe 6

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I am building a simple Windows Forms Application.

It is very simple,on my Windows PC, it runs without any problems.

If I try to copy the .exe and .pdb file on my Windows Ce device and try to start it, I get this error:

```
File or assembly name
'System.windows.forms, Version= 2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublickKeyToke= ..... or one of its dependecies, was not found.
```

My application has two simple textboxes and writes a text in a .txt file. This is the code of Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EasyManagementOrdine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string FILE_NAME = "ESPORTAZIONE.txt";

        public List<string> listaString = new List<string>();

        public StreamWriter sw;

        public Form1()
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                if (File.Exists("ESPORTAZIONE.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete("ESPORTAZIONE.txt");
                }
                this.sw = File.CreateText("ESPORTAZIONE.txt");
                //this.textQuantita.KeyPress.(new KeyPressEventHandler(this, CheckEnter));
                this.textCodiceBarre.Focus();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }

        private void codiceBarreEnter(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
                {
                    if ((!this.textCodiceBarre.Focused ? false : this.textCodiceBarre.Text.Length > 0))
                    {
                        this.textQuantita.Focus();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Exception ex = exception;
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Errore: ", ex.Message));
            }
        }

        private void quantitaEnter(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == '\r')
                {
                    if ((!this.textQuantita.Focused ? false : this.textQuantita.Text.Length > 0))
                    {
                        this.salvaQuantita();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Exception ex = exception;
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Errore: ", ex.Message));
            }
        }

        private void salvaQuantita()
        {
            try
            {
                int numeroQuantita = int.Parse(this.textQuantita.Text);
                string nuovaStringa = string.Concat(this.textCodiceBarre.Text, " && ", numeroQuantita);
                this.sw.WriteLine(nuovaStringa);
                this.textCodiceBarre.Text = "";
                this.textQuantita.Text = "";
                this.textCodiceBarre.Focus();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Exception e = exception;
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Errore: ", e.Message));
            }
        }

        private void buttonOrdine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this.sw.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Il file ESPORTAZIONE.txt è statp creato.", "Complimenti");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Exception ex = exception;
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Errore: ", ex.Message));
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                String process = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
                Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c taskkill /F /IM " + process + ".exe /T");
                Exception ex = exception;
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Errore: ", ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: what is your VS version?

Comment: You need to copy the entire bin folder to run the application, also, i'm not sure if windows.form is supported, you may need to use Microsoft.windowsce.forms

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Sorry, not ALL windows.forms classes are supported, MessageBox is the one I'm not sure, Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms MessageWindow, instead

Answer (score 0):

After read the comments....

You are using VS2017, but Visual studio from 2010 version, does not support mobile application> development for versions of Windows Phone prior to Windows Phone OS
 7.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/sa69he4t(v=vs.100)

You probably are creating a normal windows application and trying to copy it to Windows CE, it does not work that way

You neeed to use Visual Studio 2008

There you will be able to find the proper templates to create a Windows CE project...

This is irrelevant now but keep it in mind..

MessageBox class is not supported in compact framework as `.Show(String...)` is an overload of

```
Show(IWin32Window, String, ...)
```

> **Applies to**
>
> .NET Core 3.0 Preview 3
>
> .NET Framework  4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0 1.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox?view=netframework-4.7.2

You need to use `MessageWindow` class from `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms` namespace

Comment: I have import WindosCE.Forms and remove MessabeBox but it not works. The error is Windows.Form not available.....

Comment: Is your application targeting to Compact Framework??

Comment: I think that the problem is this on Compact Framework. I have used VS 2017 with .NET framework 3.5. In which mode I can developing a program to WinCe 6.0 ?

Comment: You need to use Visual Studio 2008

Comment: This is the problem, I don't have visual studio 2008 professional edition

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108102/download-and-install-visual-studio-2008